# What is so special about set theory anyway?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, soft-question

(**Later edit** - tried to clarify a couple of vague places concerning interpretations of theories that became evident in comments (thanks to Andrej Bauer, Mauro ALLEGRANZA and Emil Jeřábek). (To closers and downvoters: may I humbly direct your attention to the [soft-question](/questions/tagged/soft-question) tag down there...))

This is an ideal question: I don't even know what I am asking

It has been inspired by reading [What "metatheory" did early set theory/logic researchers use to prove semantic results?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/297942/41291)

Specifically by

> The modern approach seems to be, usually, to interpret a "model" specifically as a set in some other (typically first-order) "set metatheory." So when we talk about a model of PA, for instance, we typically mean that we are formalizing it as a subtheory of something like first-order ZFC. Models of ZFC can be formalized in stronger set theories, such as those obtained by adding large cardinals, and etc.

Indeed. It makes me wonder: there are all kinds of theories; there is a very general notion of [interpretation of one theory in another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretability); nothing about sets comes into play so far. Then all of a sudden, when one says "model", the first thing comes to mind is "a set with blablabla...". Why?

I mean, is there a rigorous way to distinguish some theories among all others by some formal property which (a) guarantees that any sensible notion of model is subsumed by interpretability in a theory with this property and (b) every theory with this property is equivalent (in some rigorous sense) to "a theory of sets"? What does this latter even mean?

Are there any other such "all-encompassing" classes of theories? This last question might seem senseless since any two "all-encompassing" theories must be mutually interpretable and thus be equivalent to each other (I think, at least in some sense?). But still maybe there is some notion of "meta-encompassing" that makes some "all-encompassings" more "all-encompassing" than others...?

Comment: Lawvere proposed using categories as an all-ecompassing basis.

Comment: The point is that a model is a collection of objects, and sets are the way we mathematically interpret the notion of a collection.

Comment: I like the question and I do not understand what is being asked. Are you looking for an answer that is different from "other set theories and type theory"?

Comment: "All-encompasing classes must encompass each other and thuse be equivalent to each other" is a non sequitur. It's even false. For instance, we can have toposes that embed into each other but are not equivalent.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You can consider as part of the question what distinguishes also the theory of categories in this respect.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If you have in mind collections in some specific sense - is it clear that a model of any kind of theory is a collection of objects? If not - do you say more than that any kind of model is a set? In this last case, it is precisely this that I am asking: why is it so?

Comment: You use these words "in mind" and "clear", as if we all share the same mind and the same notion of clarity.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I agree with you in that the question is not formulated well enough: I should emphasize that the question is not a "which"-type but rather a "why"-type question. I mean, I not so much want to know which classes of theories are "universal" in some sense but rather *what* makes them universal.

Comment: @AsafKaragila We don't?

Comment: In my mind, it's clear that we don't. If you have to ask, you're just proving my point.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Concerning the encompassing business: that was about *theories*, and I think if theories can interpret each other they are in some sense equivalent, no? I mean, in purely syntactic sense?

Comment: @AsafKaragila But we are able to make each other understand something, right? By doing so, we gradually share more common ground in our minds, to the same extent that our minds themselves do deserve more to be called minds. I believe.

Comment: I mean, ultimately there is only one reliable criterion to check whether what you think is your mind is really a mind - whether it has something in common with what others call their minds.

Comment: It is just an empirical fact that set theory has the strongest interpretive power, because it has been around a while and makes the strongest assumptions that add interpretive power (large cardinals).

Comment: @MonroeEskew Well this is one viewpoint, and it can well be an answer.

Comment: I mean, it would be nice if you could be more specific in an answer. For example, I am not sure whether you in particular say - no, there is no such rigorous property that could be formally described.

Comment: I have voted to close, since six vague questions is too many for a clear answer.

Comment: @MattF. Well that's also a good-to-know opinion :)

Comment: Because the concept of *interpretation* (which is quite old indded: in math and not only) is based on a *domain*, i.e. a "collection" of objects with suitable properties and relation. And what is the best way to formalize the concept of "collection + relations" that with set theory ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What is your reference? I thought interpretation is a purely syntactic notion, no?

Comment: Not at all : "An [interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(logic)) is an assignment of *meaning* to the symbols of a formal language. The general study of interpretations of formal languages is called *formal semantics*." "Meaning" and "semantics" deal with the relation between symbols (langugae) and objects (world).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The term “interpretation” has several unrelated meanings. I believe the OP is referring to the notion of interpretations between theories (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretability).

Comment: In what way is this an "ideal" question?

Comment: @EllieKesselman, the question is not *ideal*; it is *ideative*.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thank you, that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @EllieKesselman I had in mind that the less you know about what you are asking about the better the question is. So if you don't even know what you are asking, the question is ideal.

Comment: There is a focused soft question here, from “there is a very general notion of interpretation” to “‘a theory of sets’”.  A post limited to that section would get an upvote from me.

Comment: @MattF. Appreciated. I actually agree. It just seems to me too late to modify it this way...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I agree with other respondents that it is unlikely that one will be able to come up with some kind of *formal* argument that distinguishes set theory from other "mathematics-complete" systems (to use Mike Shulman's term, which I like!), because mathematicians are so good at rephrasing one language in terms of another.  There is surely also some degree of what one might call "historical accident" involved; we instinctively think of a model as a set because that's how we were taught, and how our teachers were taught, etc.

That said, I think a case can be made that set theory has some *psychological* advantages when it comes to addressing certain questions, e.g., is mathematics consistent? and exactly which assumptions are used to derive which theorems?  Today, most mathematicians take a rather breezy attitude towards the consistency question, assuming that it's all been sorted out by logicians and that it's no concern of theirs.  If you take consistency seriously, however, then it is vitally important to try to build everything from the ground up, one small step at a time, in as simple and clear a manner as possible.  As long as you limit yourself to finitary mathematics, several alternatives to set theory are available (arithmetic, syntax, type theory, ...), but for infinitary reasoning, set theory seems to be the psychologically best choice for most people.

Even for finitary reasoning, set theory has the advantage of being a very flexible and fine-grained tool.  In reverse mathematics, the standard approach is to consider subsystems of second-order arithmetic.  Arithmetic is certainly a natural foundation for finitary mathematics, but it quickly becomes an irresistible temptation to introduce set-theoretic reasoning because it makes it so easy to introduce any new concept or axiom that you might come up with.  That is why "second-order" arithmetic becomes the de facto foundation.

There are other goals you might have for a "foundation for mathematics" for which set theory is arguably not the optimal approach.  For example, maybe you have developed some conception of the mathematical universe, and you want some formal theory that directly captures the structures and concepts you have in mind.  Then category theory or homotopy type theory might be more attractive.  Still, I think set theory is hard to beat as a way to "get off the ground" so to speak.  To fully appreciate the merits of category theory or homotopy type theory requires a lot of prior mathematical knowledge and experience, and I think that most people would have trouble acquiring all that background knowledge without ever appealing to any set-theoretic concepts along the way.

Comment: "from the ground up": the trouble is, there is rather rough terrain out there.

Comment: Let me mention that, because of what you say, it is in principle possible that sticking to widespread paradigms created by "strong" concepts like sets, categories or types, we might be completely overlooking the whole possible directions mathematics could expand in. What if, say, my models should describe some aspects of a vortex, or a rainbow, or, say, a person with some specific neurological disroder? What does that have to do with either sets or homotopy types? Or, say, consider apparent (to me) helplessness of modern mathematics in dealing with natural language analysis...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე : This is of course always possible but I don't think that set theory is particularly worrisome here. Maybe we're missing the boat because so much of our sensory input is visual rather than olfactory or sonar, or because our brains are wired wrong, or carbon atoms have only four bonds...

Answer (score 24):

It's not clear to me whether your question is more about the role of sets versus other foundational objects, or about how set theory can be extended with large cardinal axioms to discuss models of stronger and stronger theories.  Monroe's answer addresses the latter.  Regarding the former, maybe I'll take this opportunity to push an analogy that I think deserves more currency.  In computer science there are notions such as:

- A [Turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) programming language.  All Turing-complete languages are expressive enough to simulate each other, and this is essentially the definition of the class.  In particular, a language is Turing-complete as soon as (1) it can simulate at least one known Turing-complete language and (2) it can be simulated by at least one known Turing-complete language.  Thus, to define Turing-completeness it suffices to give one example of such a language; the classical example is [Turing machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine).
- An [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) problem is, by definition, one that is solvable in polynomial time by a nondeterministic algorithm, and any other such problem can be reduced to it in polynomial time (by a deterministic algorithm).  This means that a problem is NP-complete if, and only if, (1) it can be reduced in polynomial time to some known NP-complete problem, and (2) some known NP-complete problem can be reduced to it in polynomial time.  So we could equivalently define the class of NP-complete problems by giving one example.

I suggest that we should recognize an analogous notion of a **mathematics-complete theory**: a theory which is expressive enough that all of mathematics can be encoded into it (modulo suitable extensions such as large cardinal axioms, use of stronger or weaker logics, etc.)  To define the class of mathematics-complete theories, it suffices to give one example thereof, and empirical evidence suggests that set theory is one such choice (indeed, the first to be discovered).

Mathematics-complete theories are often called *foundations for mathematics*.  I don't propose to do away with this terminology, but it sometimes produces confusion as some people seem to sometimes mean something more by it.  The phrase "mathematics-complete" emphasizes that we mean nothing more (or less) than that all of mathematics can be *encoded* into a theory, whether or not this encoding is "natural" or "intuitive".

So I guess my answer to your questions is that one such formal property is "set theory can be encoded into it, and it can be encoded into set theory".  The apparent primacy of set theory in this definition is just an artifact of the fact that set theory was the first example of such a theory; an equivalent definition would be "type theory can be encoded into it, and it can be encoded into type theory".

Comment: I like this general idea, but it’s not obvious to me how to choose a precise notion of “…can be encoded into…” that makes this work in anything like the intended/expected way, even if we restrict consideration to theories of first-order logic.  E.g. if you don’t allow some kind of axiomatic extensions, then ZFC is insufficient for many standard arguments involving universes/large categories and the like (as you point out).  But if you allow arbitrary axiomatic extensions, then “the first-order language of $\in$” must already be considered math-complete, which seems weaker than intended.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Good question.  What about starting with a first-order theory like ZFC and allowing axiomatic extensions *of it*?

Comment: I have a similar but slightly different doubt. How do we know that mathematics will always stay within bounds encodable in set theory (whatever this means)? There is additional specifics that development of mathematics is influenced by current paradigms. In principle it can be the case that at any moment somebody comes up with something important that transcends the set-theoretic paradigm, and then, who knows? That's why am asking about some formal rigorous detectable properties. But of course there might be none.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე It seems to me that it would be impossible *in principle* to know that any formal definition definitely encompasses every new kind of mathematics that *might* be invented some day in the future.  That said, it seems unlikely to me that a totally new kind of mathematics would be able to gain any foothold without at least a translation into existing mathematics.

Comment: Conway says something similar in On Numbers and Games. "It seems to us, however, that mathematics has now reached the stage where formalisation within some particular axiomatic set theory is irrelevant, even for foundational studies. It should be possible to specify conditions on a mathematical theory which would suffice for embeddability within ZF...but which do not otherwise restrict the possible constructions in that theory...This appendix is in fact a cry for a  Mathematicians' Liberation Movement!"

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine by the way, once a particular first-order theory is bi-interpretable with ZFC, then we can translate any large cardinal axiom expressed in ZFC language over to that other theory.  Of course the result may not be the most "natural" way to formulate the analogous principle there, but one might argue that this shows that we don't need to worry about simultaneously chararcterizing "a mathematics-complete theory including all of its large-cardinal extensions" -- once we have a certain amount of strength, the rest can be obtained automatically.

Comment: @MikeShulman: Sure! But my point is that if we want to say “ZFC is math-complete” without saying “The empty theory over the language $\{\in\}$ is math-complete”, then it seems to me we need to explain why the extension of ZFC to (ZFC + large cardinals) is “negligible” (so that when challenged to encode universe-based arguments in ZFC, it’s ok to say “just assume them”) but the extension of the empty theory to ZFC isn’t negligible in the same way. Without such an explanation, I’m not convinced it’s possible to define a non-trivial notion of “math-complete” along the appealing lines you sketch.

Comment: @Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine. What is an example of a particular first-order theory which is bi-interpretable with ZFC?

Comment: @AndréHenriques: I don’t have any such examples in mind — why do you ask?  Or did you mean to ask Mike, not me?

Comment: @MikeShulman. Yes, Peter. -- sorry. I meant to ask Mike.

Comment: @AndréHenriques ETCS+R is one, or more generally the first-order theory of an autological elementary topos.  If you're willing to move beyond first-order logic, then various forms of type theory can be used too.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Since we observe empirically that ZFC and its extensions are mathematics-complete in the informal sense, we could formally simply define a theory to be "mathematics-complete" if it is biinterpretable with ZFC.  Any such theory then automatically inherits a tower of large cardinal extensions by translation from ZFC.  The empty theory over $\{\in\}$ is then not mathematics-complete because it is not biinterpretable with ZFC.  This definition appears to privilege ZFC, but it's no worse than privileging Turing machines (say) in defining Turing-completeness.

Comment: @Mike Shulman. Is ZF biinterpretable in ZFC?

Comment: @AndréHenriques Yes.  Any model of ZFC is also a model of ZF, and inside any model of ZF you can build Godel's constructible universe L which satisfies ZFC.

Comment: @AndréHenriques ZF and ZFC are mutually interpretable, [not bi-interpretable](http://jdh.hamkins.org/different-set-theories-are-never-bi-interpretable/).

Comment: @user76284 Thanks.  I constantly make the mistake of assuming that "bi-interpretable" means what it *sounds* like it should mean, which logicians call "mutually interpretable" instead.

Answer (score 17):

It is my understanding that set theory's interpretive power is a quasi-empirical fact, and that at present there is no grand theoretical explanation of the phenomenon.  By "set theory," I mean the mathematical research area, not a specific formal theory.

Set theory has strong interpretive power in the sense that it provides a "measuring stick" for gauging the relative consistency (aka interpretability) of mathematical theories in general--the large cardinal hierarchy.  We do not have an explanation for why this system should appear as a measuring *stick* rather than a partial order, but it appears to be a well-ordered hierarchy.  Large cardinals have had enough success in proving relative consistency results that we have come to accept them as the arbiters of consistency (of strong enough theories).

The fact that large cardinal concepts are formalized in set theory rather than some other foundational theory is a historical fact.  Things could have conceivably turned out differently.  The study of interpretability of weaker theories is typically done in the context of subsystems of second-order arithmetic, where the notion of set plays a much smaller role.

One could raise the following objection to the large cardinal hierarchy as an ultimate arbiter.  There are many unsolved relative consistency questions.  Proving these statements consistent/independent relative to large cardinals would be considered a solution.  But perhaps there are statements that will not be measured by large cardinals because their consistency strength is not comparable to large cardinals.  Our belief in the supremacy of large cardinals (or social conformity to the practice) just prevents us from designating other statements as important nodes in the sea of consistency strengths.  An incomparable statement would remain invisible to us as such.

Comment: I think something can be said in the direction of why large cardinals measure consistency.  Namely, essentially the only mathematical tool we have to prove things about infinite objects in finite language is induction, and so the strength of a theory consists in how many "inductive arguments" it asserts are well-founded.  And as for the linear ordering, at least in classical logic any well-founded relation is bisimulable to a (linear) well-ordering.  (Accordingly, in intuitionistic logic, I see no reason to expect "large cardinal axioms" to be analogously linearly ordered.)

Comment: I don't think this idea explains large cardinals up to a certain level, like measurable cardinals.  These have implications for the "width" of the universe, not merely "height," i.e. how far up induction takes you.

Comment: why does the fact that "if the universe is X high then it must also be Y wide" mean that we can't explain axioms about the height of the universe in terms of their inductive power?  Obviously with a stronger induction principle you can prove more, and I don't see why statements about the "width" of the universe (whatever that means) should be considered any different from other consequences of such an induction principle that you can't prove without it.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me that the existence of a measurable cardinal is an "induction principle."  Measurable cardinals are not measurable in all inner models (classes satisfying ZF with the same ordinals and thus the same notion of well-foundedness), so this seems like a counterexample to the claim that they are some kind of "induction principle."

Comment: It's not clear to me that just because the ordinals in a model of ZF happen to be (*externally* to that model) isomorphic to the ordinals in some other model, it follows that the two models have the "same notion of well-foundedness" in whatever sense is relevant, since whatever that means it must be an *internal* notion.  I don't even know what it would mean to say that two *different* models have "the same notion of well-foundedness".

Comment: Ok well this is quite well known. If M is a submodel of N with the same ordinals, both satisfying ZF, and R is a relation in M, then M and N agree on whether R is well-founded.  (To be fair, this is an important and nontrivial absoluteness theorem.)

Comment: Yes, I know that; I'm objecting to the claim that that means that "M and N have the same notion of well-foundedness."  Or, I suppose, if that's your definition of "the same notion of well-foundedness", then I don't see why it is any sort of counterexample to the claim that a measurable cardinal is an induction principle.  Just because it so happens that M and N, as sets in some external metatheory, happen to agree about which elements of that metatheory are well-founded, doesn't mean that M and N have the same *internal* "ideas" about what well-foundedness means or how much induction is valid.

Comment: In fact, it could just as easily go the other way: the fact that measurability is not preserved in inner models could be taken to imply that "having the same ordinals" in this external sense is *not* a characterization of "having the same notion of well-foundedness".

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "internal ideas of well-foundedness."  They have the same ordinals and so can do induction to exactly the same levels.  What are you getting at?

Comment: M and N are two *different* models of set theory.  What does it mean to say that they have "the same" levels?  If I have two models $G,H$ of the theory of a group, even if there happens to be a "canonical" embedding of one into the other, an element of $G$ might have different properties *qua* element of $G$ than *qua* element of $H$.

Comment: Similarly, even though there is a bijection between the elements of M that M calls "ordinals" and the elements of N that N calls "ordinals", there's no reason to believe that a pair of elements that correspond under that bijection necessarily represent "the same level of inductive strength" inside of the models M and N.

Comment: I’m talking about a situation in which the ordinals between the two models are *identitical* (although isomorphic will do just fine).  This means that they do inducitive constructions of exactly the same lengths.  Furthermore, all the objects they have in common which are capable of some kind of inductive analysis in one model are this way in the other model. (This is the absoluteness theorem I mentioned.)  Now, what do *you* mean by “inductive strength”?

Comment: I agree with Monroe Eskew. Suppose I even grant Mike Shulman that the fact the two models have the same ordinals is not a "counterexample to the claim that a measurable cardinal is an induction principle." Fine. But on what grounds are you claiming that the existence of a measurable cardinal *is* an induction principle? It certainly doesn't *look* like an induction principle upon superficial examination. What makes something an induction principle? Can you give an example of an axiom that is definitely *not* an induction principle, and if so, why is it not an induction principle?

Comment: This conversation doesn't seem to be going anywhere (we're each repeating ourselves), so let's give it up.

Comment: You couldn’t respond adequately.